# configuring asp.net web.config for Paypal

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I copied the following web.config from the github paypal net sdk page, but got an error saying could not find schema information for the element ;Paypal'.  Is there something wrong with my web.config syntax (this is for an asp.net website):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="_client_Id_"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="_client_secret_"/>
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears correct according to [the documentation found here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters#how-to-configure).

Are you sure that you have the appropriate references included for Paypal (via NuGet or manually)?

Additionally, you appear to be missing an opening `<configuration>` element, which could be an issue as well (unless that is just a typo) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="_client_Id_"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="_client_secret_"/>
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

Comment: [This page](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Configuration) has the correct web.config settings for the PayPal .NET SDK.  The link you're pointing to is the older Core SDK that is now only used with the Classic SDKs (Merchant, Adaptive Payments, etc.).  The main difference between the two is the namespace for `SDKConfigHandler`, which was changed in the PayPal .NET SDK to avoid a namespace conflict.  Other than that, this answer is correct. :)

Comment: It still doesn't work, even if I put in the section: "<section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK" />" instead of the one specified on the page.  I did install the Paypal NET SDK, and the package file tells me I have: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="PayPal" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>

Comment: @GordonDugan is this related to [this issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/94) on GitHub?

Comment: Yes, its the same issue.  I find now that the error was NOT in web.config, but it created errors that VS "thought" were in the web.config.